# c++ Проблема с матрицей поворота в 2d-пространстве

Tags: c++, консоль, матрицы

Возникла проблема с матрицами поворота - квадрат начинает сильно поворачивать(к примеру при ~17 градусах квадрат уже достигает ~45 градусов), а после и вовсе вращаться в обратную сторону

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

//размеры карты
#define HEIGHT 64
#define WIDTH 64

#define radian(a) ((a * 3.1415926535) / 180) //перевод из градусов в радианы

char map[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

//магическая штука для переноса указателя консоли в самое начало
void gotoxy(SHORT x = 0, SHORT y = 0) {
    static HANDLE h = NULL;  
    if(!h)
        h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD c = { x, y };  
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(h,c);
}

void saveTerrain() {
    std::ofstream fout("map.save");
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
            fout << map[i][j];
        }
        fout << std::endl;
    }

    fout.close();
}

struct vector2 {
    float x;
    float y;
};

class Object {
public:
    vector2 center;
    double angle;
    std::vector<vector2> points; //при этом вектора относительно ЦЕНТРА

    Object(vector2 setCenter, std::vector<vector2> setPoints) {
        center = setCenter;
        points = setPoints;
    }

    void setPos(vector2 setPos) {
        center = setPos;
    }

    void setRotate(double setAngle) { angle = setAngle; checkRotate(); }
    void addRotate(double addAngle) { angle += addAngle; checkRotate(); }

    void checkRotate() {
        if (angle > 360) { angle = angle - 360; }
        for (long long unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
            vector2 oldPos = points[i];

            //матрица поворота
            points[i].x = oldPos.x * cos(radian(angle)) - oldPos.y * sin(radian(angle));
            points[i].y = oldPos.x * sin(radian(angle)) + oldPos.y * cos(radian(angle));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    //создание квадрата
    std::vector<vector2> points;
    points.push_back(vector2{-1, -1});
    points.push_back(vector2{1, -1});
    points.push_back(vector2{-1, 1});
    points.push_back(vector2{1, 1});
    Object obj(vector2{10, 10}, points);

    //флаг для того, чтобы показывать в консоли вершины фигуры
    bool isNeedToDraw;

    //obj.setRotate(450);

    while (true) {
        gotoxy(0, 0);
        obj.addRotate(1); //каждые 100 миллисекунд к повороту фигуры прибавляется градус
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
                for (long long unsigned int k = 0; k < obj.points.size(); ++k) {
                    if (int((obj.points[k].x * 5 + obj.center.x * 5)) == j && int((obj.points[k].y * 5 + obj.center.y * 5)) == i) { //если позиция соответствует положению в консоли, то
                        isNeedToDraw = true;
                    }
                }
                if (isNeedToDraw) {
                    map[i][j] = '#';
                    std::cout << map[i][j];
                } else {
                    map[i][j] = i;
                    std::cout << ' ';
                }
                isNeedToDraw = false;
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << obj.angle << std::endl;
        _sleep(100);
    }

    //saveTerrain();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы каждый раз поворачиваете фигуру на угол angle не исходную, а последнюю... Т.е., грубо говоря, на градус, потом еще на 2, потом еще на 3 и так далее. Грубо говоря, с ускорением...

Меняем несколько строк

```
std::vector<vector2> points; //при этом вектора относительно ЦЕНТРА
std::vector<vector2> start; //при этом вектора относительно ЦЕНТРА

Object(vector2 setCenter, std::vector<vector2> setPoints) {
    center = setCenter;
    points = start = setPoints;
}
```

и

```
    for (long long unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {

        //матрица поворота
        points[i].x = start[i].x * cos(radian(angle)) - start[i].y * sin(radian(angle));
        points[i].y = start[i].x * sin(radian(angle)) + start[i].y * cos(radian(angle));
    }
```

и все работает как надо...

Comment: Ох, спасибо! Домой приду и посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Ну а чего Вы ждёте? Вы сначала повернули квадрат на 1°, потом **уже повёрнутый** квадрат повернулся на 2°, накопилось 3° вместо 2°, потом повёрнутый на 3° квадрат поворачивается ещё на 3°, уже в этот момент угол будет двойным, то есть 6° вместо 3°, дальше Вы поворачиваете ещё на 4°, накапливается 10°, потом поворот ещё на 5°, накапливается 15°, то есть уже тройной угол, потом Вы поворачиваете на 6°, накапливается 21°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 7°, накапливается 28°, то есть угол больше уже в четыре раза, потом Вы поворачиваете на 8°, накапливается 36°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 9°, накапливается 45°, то есть уже пятикратный угол, потом Вы поворачиваете на 10°, накапливается 55°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 11°, накапливается 66°, то есть шестикратный угол, потом Вы потом Вы поворачиваете на 12°, накапливается 78°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 13°, накапливается 91°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 14°, накапливается 105°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 15°, накапливается 120°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 16°, накапливается 136°, потом Вы поворачиваете на 17°, накапливается 153°. Поворачивать надо или каждый раз только на приращение угла, или каждый раз исходное положение, которое было до всех поворотов.

Comment: Разве в имеющемся ответе не об этом говорится?